# The argument pattern (a new idea vs. bind vs. self/that patterns)

Tags: javascript, syntax, callback, semantics, readability

For accesing "this" of a parrent in a callback we use mostly two common patterns:

(1st) — **the that (self, me, ..) pattern**:

```
this.something = "hello";
var that = this;

var callback = function(){
    console.log(that.something);  // hello
};

callback();
```

(2nd) — **the bind pattern**:

```
this.something = "hello";

var callback = function(){
    console.log(this.something);  // hello
}.bind(this);

callback();
```

.. but today I've figured out that we actually can use also **a pattern with arguments**, that is cleaner, compatibile and working as well:

```
this.something = "hello";

var callback = function(self){
    console.log(self.something); // hello
};

(callback)(this);
```

The advantages are clear:
 - no needed for an excess inheritation
 - very simple syntax and readability
 - compatibility (with browsers like ie6)
 - a bit of the functional approach (it's only a parameter)

What do you think about it?

Comment: SO isn't for opinion-based questions. `callback.call(this)` seems like a neater way to do the same thing.

Comment: everything is an opinon. i haven't seen the universal and perfect solution in last 10 years in IT ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the advantages of this pattern without a Python-style `self` argument:

```
this.something = "hello";

var callback = function() {
    console.log(this.something); // hello
};

callback.call(this);
```